# android sort ArrayList according to a obj data

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting, collections

My list

```
ArrayList<MyList> list = new ArrayList<MyList>();
 //        name    - order - info
list.add("Book ...", "1", "blah blah);
list.add("Book ...", "10", "blah blah);
list.add("Book ...", "11", "blah blah);
list.add("Book ...", "2", "blah blah);
```

I want to sort the list according to its position in the 2 second obj

Then I tried

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

List Calss

```
public class MyList implements Comparable<MyList> {

...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull MyList content) {
        return Integer.parseInt(content.getOrder());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a `Comparator` object to the `sort` method.

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<MyList>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyList m1, MyList m2) {
        return m1.getOrder() - m2.getOrder();
    }
});
```

If you're using java 8 you could do this.

```
Collections.sort(list, (MyList m1, MyList m2) -> 
                                   m1.getOrder() - m2.getOrder()));
```

Comment: Nice! This way you can do different Comparisons in different circumstances! Sweet!

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<MyList> list = new ArrayList<MyList>();
     //        name    - order - info
    list.add("Book ...", "1", "blah blah);
    list.add("Book ...", "10", "blah blah);
    list.add("Book ...", "11", "blah blah);
    list.add("Book ...", "2", "blah blah);

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<MyList>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(MyList m1, MyList m2) {
            return m1.getOrder() - m2.getOrder();
        }
    });
```

**now check your list is in ascending order.**

Answer (score 1):

You need a **[Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)** here.

That one compares **two** items, and returns -1, 0, or 1; if the first entry is smaller, equal, bigger than the second one.

But you should go one step further: it seems like you try to model certain data - then don't use a **flat** MyList list class. Create a class that really **models** your data; maybe a *BookRecord*; that has fields like `String name`, or `int id`.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `compareTo` method look like:

```
    public int compareTo(MyList o) {
        return this.getOrder() - o.getOrder();
    }
```